# Broken launcher icon for FlightGear

Tags: 11.10

I'm using FlightGear and the icon isn't shows properly on ubuntu 11.10 and the icon for the launcher is broken.

How do I fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The icon link is just broken, to fix it edit the launcher with

```
sudo nano /usr/share/applications/flightgear.desktop
```

and make it so that the last line has this content

```
Icon=/usr/share/games/FlightGear/Aircraft/Generic/Logos/fgshield.png
```

Note that you can also use another image of your preference.